# Fetch list of numbers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have used beautiful soup to fetch a class

```
soup.select('.pr-xs')
```

which results in

```
    [<span class="instructor-block__students-subscribed pl-xs pr-xs">
     1,184,500 students
   </span>, <span class="instructor-block__students-subscribed pl-xs pr-xs">
     697,000 students
   </span>, <span class="instructor-block__students-subscribed pl-xs pr-xs">
     167,500 students
   </span>, <span class="instructor-block__students-subscribed pl-xs pr-xs">
     145,500 students
   </span>, <span class="instructor-block__students-subscribed pl-xs pr-xs">
     81,000 students
   </span>, <span class="instructor-block__students-subscribed pl-xs pr-xs">
     172,000 students
   </span>]
```

Now I want a new list contains only numbers like

```
['1184500, 697000, 167500,145500,81000,172000]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried or what problems you got through your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the help of regression functions

```
import re
students = [re.sub(',', '', re.findall('[\d,]+', str(i))[0]) for i in soup.select('.pr-xs')]
```

this will give you the result as

```
['1184500','697000','167500','145500','81000','172000']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the following result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
data = [item.text.split("students")[0].strip() for item in soup.select('.pr-xs')]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['1,184,500', '697,000', '167,500', '145,500', '81,000', '172,000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to find the numbers:

```
import re
numbers = [re.sub(',', '', re.findall('[\d,]+', str(i))[0]) for i in soup.select('.pr-xs')]
```